# google actions: Actions SDK IntentHandler not found for intent:

Tags: actions-on-google

I am using google actions using actions sdk. I find intermittently (after 10+ requests), I get an error `Actions SDK IntentHandler not found for intent: at Function.<anonymous>`.

The Actions project has a Google Functions fulfillment webhook whose structure is as below:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {
  actionssdk,
  SimpleResponse,
  BasicCard,
  Button,
  Image,
  Suggestions,
  List,
  MediaObject,
  Permission,
  SignIn
} = require('actions-on-google');

const CLIENT_ID = ...
const app = actionssdk({clientId: CLIENT_ID});

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv) => {
...
});

app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', (conv) => {
...
});

app.intent('actions.intent.SIGNIN', (conv) => {
...
});

app.intent('actions.intent.OPTION', (conv) => {
...
});

app.intent('actions.intent.CANCEL', (conv) => {
...
});

exports.fulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Can anyone direct me on the likely reason for this error? There is no other error log visible. Thanks

Comment: To add I set `debug:true` and noticed that randomly and intermittently the request log shows blank `{}`

Comment: Have you spotted out the problem?